# How to improve speed of getting data from SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I am new to asp.net mvc5. I have a model `Shipping` and my `dbo.Shippings.sql` is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shippings] 
(
    [Id]                INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TruckerId]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
.........more there...

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Shippings] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Shippings_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApplicationUserId]
    ON [dbo].[Shippings]([ApplicationUserId] ASC);
```

And my first page must shows all shippings that not sold (`if shipping.truckerId == null` means not sold yet)

In my `ShippingController` I have below:

```
// GET: Shipping
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
        //below is sorting
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.FromSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "from_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DestSortParm = sortOrder == "Destination" ? "dest_desc" : "Destination";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        //below is searching state and zipcode
        var shippings = from s in db.Shippings
                        where s.TruckerId == null
                        select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            shippings = shippings.Where(s => s.FromState.Contains(searchString)//from state
                                   || s.DestState.Contains(searchString)//dest state
                                   || s.FromZipCode.Contains(searchString)//from zipcode
                                   || s.DestZipCode.Contains(searchString));//dest zipcode
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "from_desc":
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.From);
                break;
            case "Destination":
                shippings = shippings.OrderBy(s => s.Destination); //not working
                break;
            case "dest_desc":
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Destination); //not working
                break;
            default:
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.OrderDateTime);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(shippings.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        //return View(shippings.ToList());

}
```

I think:

```
var shippings = from s in db.Shippings
                where s.TruckerId == null
                select s;
```

is not clever way to get shippings and it is very slow if the db gets bigger..

I only need to show its FromCity, FromState, FromZipCode, PickUpDateTime, DestCity, DestState, DestZipCode, Price, Content, and TruckerId which tells it is sold or not.

Please help!

**Edited and Update:**
At the time I was asking this question I was fairly new to web development and database.
I was able to make better performance by creating indexes for db. So quickly lookup possible.
Also I re made the architecture of web app. 
Also I created a View for shipping that were not sold. So always if the web hit the view from db, it will does not have to spend time for filtering out.

Comment: first things to speed  to create appropriate indexs . specially on the column which are used in where clause . lok for non clustred index . Also you can use sql profile to get the sql generated and then analyze the query plan

Comment: And use appropriate datatypes. You have varchar(max) all over the place. Do you really anticipate tracking numbers to exceed 8,000 characters? And don't use float and real to hold values that you want precision with. They are approximate datatypes. Use numeric instead. Just using the correct datatypes will greatly decrease the width of your rows.

Comment: Same question as here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167259/how-to-improve-speed-of-getting-data-from-sql-database-asp-mvc

Comment: @SeanLange what is the best data type for price and length(inch)?

Comment: The table is fine but your probably going to need more clauses and a paging based query to handle this table as it gets larger...thinking millions of records. Your issues are all going to relate to the number of results you need to pull more then anything.

Comment: You need to realize first that float and real are the same exact thing in sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx For exact number...like I said before...you should use numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enought reputation to comment, i'll delete this, or remake to answer !!!

What about :

1. adding some enum status(sold,active,in rent,...) or only making bool value for sold if you dont need more statuses
2. Or maybe some *optimalization* (like reduce NVARCHAR(MAX) maybe to possible longest value so for example attribute name as NVARCHAR(20)

P.S. : I think, that this select insn't slowing down a lot ....